# Effect of padding sequences in MultiHeadAttention (TensorFlow/Keras)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, padding, masking, attention-model

I am trying to use the `MultiHeadAttention` layer to process `variable-length` sets of elements, that is, sequences where the order is not important (otherwise I would try `RNNs`). The problem is that I'm not sure I'm understanding the effect of padding in the input sequence. My point is that the output of a sequence including elements 1 and 2 should be equal to the output of the same sequence with 0's padding to a given length. In other words, the input `[1, 2]` and `[1, 2, 0]` (or even `[1, 2, 0, 0, 0 ... ]` should yield the same output regarding the true inputs (1, and 2, I don't mind the output for the 0s because I know it is a "fake" input to pad). The following is a piece of code to show the different outputs depending on the padding.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

max_tokens = 10  # maximum length of any sequence
dimension = 5  # dimension of the vectors in the embedding

# Variable-length int sequences.
query_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(None,), dtype='int32')
value_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(None,), dtype='int32')

handmade_embedding = np.arange(max_tokens).reshape(max_tokens, 1) * np.ones(dimension)

# Embedding lookup.
token_embedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim=max_tokens, output_dim=dimension, mask_zero=True,
                                            embeddings_initializer=tf.constant_initializer(handmade_embedding),
                                            trainable=False)

# Query embeddings of shape [batch_size, Tq, dimension].
query_embeddings = token_embedding(query_input)
# Value embeddings of shape [batch_size, Tv, dimension].
value_embeddings = token_embedding(value_input)

attention_output, weights = \
    tf.keras.layers.MultiHeadAttention(num_heads=10, key_dim=10)(query=query_embeddings,
                                                                 value=value_embeddings,
                                                                 return_attention_scores=True)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[query_input, value_input],
                       outputs=[query_embeddings, attention_output])
names = ('query_embeddings', 'attention_output')

model.summary()

q = np.array([[1, 2, 0]])
prediction = model.predict([q, q])  # self-attention

print('\nWITH PADDING')
for n, v in zip(names, prediction):
    print(f'\n{n}:\n{v}')

q = q[:, :-1]  # remove the padding column in this example
prediction = model.predict([q, q])  # self-attention
print('\nWITHOUT PADDING')
for n, v in zip(names, prediction):
    print(f'\n{n}:\n{v}')
```

The output of the MultiHeadAttention layer with padding is the following:

```
attention_output:
[[[-0.0374077  -0.03303239 -0.02354158 -0.04111823  0.08189851]
  [-0.04877335 -0.04348412 -0.012391   -0.04778382  0.09745573]
  [-0.02586985 -0.02244503 -0.03482261 -0.03429744  0.06620502]]]
```

and without padding:

```
attention_output:
[[[-0.04313684 -0.03764199 -0.04799934 -0.05400878  0.10519686]
  [-0.04743624 -0.041591   -0.04378954 -0.05654225  0.11106053]]]
```

I expected the first and second output vectors to be the same but it is not the case. I plan to process later those vectors and to summarize them into a single vector (average, or whatever), but I would like deterministic outputs regarding the length of the padding. What am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after some months of letting the code rest in my computer, now it seems it is not even needed the attention_mask. Now the output is why I expected, i.e., the same for the true entries. Maybe there were some internal changes in TensorFlow affecting this. I'm going a bit crazy...

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `attention_mask argument` to `Multihead_Attention()` call.

Comment: But the ```attention_mask``` is a static one, fixed in the definition of the layer. However, during the training, the batches will have different variable-length sequences... so I don’t see how to use it. I mean, the first hypothetical batch of examples could be
```[[1, 2, 0, 0, 0],
 [3, 5, 4, 9, 0],
...
[8, 3, 9, 5, 2]]```
while another one could have no padding:
```[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[4, 3, 2, 7, 8]
...
[6, 3, 8, 9, 2]]```

I think I’m looking for a parameter such as ```mask_zero``` to automatically discard the padding vectors, i.e. the 0’s in the input sequences.

Comment: Attention mask is a call argument. So it is not fixed in the layer definition. I don't have nightly build installed. So I can not try. But I doubt it is static. You can easily convert your input to mask using something like `tf.math.equal(seq, 0)`. But you need to use custom loop (instead of `fit()`, `predict()`) because of this additional argument

Comment: Ok, thanks, I’ll try in a near future, but I need more time to become familiar with all those internals of TensorFlow. However, I wish the stable (not nightly) version of MultiHeadAttention takes into account a parameter ```mask``` as, for example, LSTM does. It would be the perfect solution for me.

Comment: MultiHeadAttention already takes mask into account like LSTM does. I've just found out that MultiHeadAttention is already in stable version (but within tfa package): see tfa.layers.MultiHeadAttention